# How to print "key" value of a list of key:value pairs?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of key:value pairs.
How do I print each one of them separately?

```
NetworkCommands = [
    (target + '/network/vlan'              , {"vlan": 30, "tagged_ports": [1,2], "ip": "172.0.10.1/16"}),
    (target + '/network/vlan'              , {"vlan": 51, "tagged_ports": [1,2], "ip": "10.0.0.1/16"}),
    (target + '/network/apply'             , {}),
    (target + '/network/sr/routing/static' , {"vlan": 51, "dest_ip": "100.0.0.0/8", "gateway": "10.0.0.2"}),
    (target + '/network/apply'             , {}),
]
```

This prints both:

```
for i in NetworkCommands:
    print(i)

('https://sonia:443/network/vlan', {'ip': '172.0.10.1/16', 'vlan': 30, 'tagged_ports': [1, 2]})
('https://sonia:443/network/vlan', {'ip': '10.0.0.1/16', 'vlan': 51, 'tagged_ports': [1, 2]})
('https://sonia:443/network/apply', {})
('https://sonia:443/network/sr/routing/static', {'vlan': 51, 'gateway': '10.0.0.2', 'dest_ip': '100.0.0.0/8'})
('https://sonia:443/network/apply', {})
```

Comment: instead of `print(i)` do `print(i[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use argument unpacking to assign each of the two elements in each tuple to their own variable.

```
for first, second in NetworkCommands:
    print('The first element is', first)
    print('The second element is ', second)
```

Alternatively, just index the tuple as required.

```
for i in NetworkCommands:
    print('The first element is', i[0])
    print('The second element is', i[1])
```